# Java Client Certificate Conflict

Tags: java, security, client-certificates, certificate-store

I have a working app that connects to a lot of external services.  I'm adding a new SOAP client that requires client authentication.  I'm able to get it working, but not without breaking other things in the app, so I'm really confused as to what's going on.  Some quick background:

1. We're using the default cacerts file and have imported a lot of trusted certs there.
2. We created a private key, generated a cert req from it, got a cert back, and created a p12 file containing the cert and private key that is used for client auth.
3. If we specify that p12 file as the keystore for the app the SOAP client works:

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="keystore.p12" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="password" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType="pkcs12"

4. If we do not do the above, but instead import this into the cacerts file doing:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -destkeystore cacerts -srcstoretype pkcs12

it does NOT work!  Nor does it work if we do this and specify cacerts as the keystore per step 3 (excluding the last arg, as it's a different store type, right?)

So, with steps 1-3 we have our new integration working, but the problem is that other stuff in the app now breaks!  No other keystore was being specified before (my understanding is that it defaults to cacerts anyway).  We now have errors such as with AWS's SES (email) service throwing exceptions such as:

- java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't instantiate instance of class com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient
- com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to access default SSL context
- java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
- java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Can someone explain to me what's causing this conflict and how to resolve it?  Thanks much for your help!

Jeff

Comment: Have you checked if you have an admin rights to access jre security libraries/folders. Sometimes if you don't admin rights, you might get these kind of exceptions.

Comment: Cacerts is the trust store not the key store.

Comment: I do have access to cacerts - I've added certs to trust there before and that's worked fine.  I'm confused about the difference between a key and trust store.  Conceptually I get it, but when I specify a specific key store other stuff breaks and nothing else is configured.  Per java docs and my files it looks like it should be dropping to cacerts for the keystore as well.

Comment: No to the last; for a client the *truststore* (or internally `TrustManager`) determines whether a server can identity itself to you, and defaults to `JREHOME/lib/{jsse,}cacerts`; the *keystore* (`KeyManager`) allows you to prove your identity to some (fairly few) servers, and defaults to nothing. These can be different files, but since they both can use JKS format they *can* be the same file, as you are attempting.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at the docs and it really should be dropping to cacerts as the key store - the jsse (or anything sillier) doesn't exist.  My guess is that there's a key or something that other stuff needs in cacerts which is why things blow up when I try to use another key store.  But that still leaves me baffled as to why importing the key into cacerts isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain but likely:

JKS format can have a password on a privatekey entry different from the password on the containing store (file) but many apps including all using `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` properties can't handle that.

Either make sure the pre-import password on the p12 (which is a single password covering the store and the key) is the same as the store password on the target jks (which for `cacerts` as installed is `changeit`) or specify both `-deststorepass -destkeypass` with the same value.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I tired re-generating the p12 with a password of "changeit", imported into cacerts again (overwriting the same alias) and had the same result.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Jeff057: that's surprising. Please try `keytool -keystore cacerts -certreq -alias $name` and see what it prompts for: only the keystore password, or also the key password. (I know we don't _want_ another CSR; discard any output. This is only a test.) If `keytool` is able to access using only the store passward, JSSE should also.

Comment: Thanks again for the response Dave!  I ran the command and it prompted only for the keystore password (changeit) and it then printed the cert.  So it *should* work, but doesn't...

Comment: I finally got this working!  I'm still not quite sure what was going on, but having the same password I think helped, and I had to have the certs in the key store also imported into the trust store.  That seemed to be what did it, though I'm still a bit confused.  Thanks for your help!